# How to Concat JS variable with PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I am using Laravel with VueJS
I have a simple code.

```
        <div class="large-6 columns properties" v-for="property in selectedProperties">
       <h6 class="ribbon" v-if="property.discount"><strong>@{{property.discount}} % OFF </strong></h6>
        <div class="card">
      <img src="{{asset("storage/$hotel->image")}}"> //Here i need to use property.image instead of $hotel->image
//How can i use this Js variable in asset() of php? 
      <div class="card-section">
    @{{property.name}}

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

How can i use `property.image` instead of `$hotel->image` in `asset()` function of laravel/PHP?

Comment: in the same way as you used above `<strong>@{{property.discount}} % OFF </strong>`

Comment: So Lke this  `<img src="@{{asset("storage/property.image")}}">` ? OR like this `<img src="{{asset("storage/@{{property.image}}")}}">` ?

Comment: Use `<img src="{{asset("storage")}}/@{{property.image}}">`

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for answer.  By doing your way it is not rendering the value of `propery.image` if i check url it is something like this which is not should be. `http://localhost:8000/storage/%7B%7Bproperty.image%7D%7D` This means it is rendering `property.image` as a string because it is in `" "`

Comment: How about `<img v-bind:src="{{asset("storage/")}} + property.image'">` ?

Comment: @apokryfos No. that also not working